# iOS Development vs Production App Facebook Login Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, api

I’m having issues with using Facebook login with my iOS app. I have everything working perfectly, but when I deploy the app for review or for use with TestFlight, the Facebook login suddenly stops working.
As soon as I make a request to FBSDKGraphRequest I’m not getting any further feedback from the app. It doesn’t crash, but nothing within the block is executed; there isn’t even an error thrown inside the block that I can read. And I can’t debug it much because it only happens with the production version of the app.
If anyone knows anything about this I would greatly appreciate the help. I’ve built my entire app and I’m stuck with this issue and I have no idea how to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run app with in real device , Some times it may not work in the simulator. 
Also please make sure your production bundle id is same as your facebook developer account bundle id.

Comment: I've done both and verified the bundle id. It runs well when running the development version on any device. As soon as a device runs a production version (app submission review, test flight, etc) it can't get past the FBSDKGraphRequest login event.